# C - Call a function

Tags: c

I want to get a value from a function in other function i think i have to call a function in other function, then call it on main, but how?

```
void funcA(PEOPLE people[], int *total)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char line[100];
    fp = fopen("example.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
    exit(1);
    }

    else {
    fgets(line, 100, fp);   //get a number from the txt
    total = atoi(line); //convert to int
    }
}

void funcB(PEOPLE people[], int *total)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < total; i++) {
    printf("%s\n", people[i].name);
    }
    funcA(people, &total);
}

void main()
{
    PEOPLE people[100];
    int *total;
    funcB(people, &total);
}
```

What i'm doing wrong? I need the value from total to do cicle for;

Comment: Please indent correctly your code.

Comment: Unless I am reading this wrong, not sure if this even compiles.  Granted I have not written strait C in awhile.  So you are passing in an array of PERSON into a method that takes an array of PEOPLE.  Also, you are doing an atoi in linha which I do not see declared anywhere.  What is the array that s being passed around actually used for.  The funcA does not use it.  So I guess my question is what are you trying to accomplish, and what is your code not doing?

Answer (score 1):

First, you should call `funcA` from `funcB` like this:

```
funcA(people, total);
```

Then, if I understand you correctly, you want to *return* a value from your function(s). You can do it like this:

```
int funcA(PEOPLE people[], int *total){
  int ret;
  // set ret to desired value
  return ret;
}
...
int value = funcA(people, total);
```

After sorting this out, you need to initialize your variables correctly, sort out the naming discrepancies (linha vs line, PEOPLE vs PERSON) and all other issues noted by others.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous problems here (total is a pointer, for loop on the pointer, never initialized to anything, etc etc).

To answer your question, functions have return types:

```
 int foo(void) {
     return 3;
 }

 int main(int argc, char**argv) {
    printf("Foo returned %d\n", foo());
    return 0;
 }
```

In this case foo returns `int`. You return values with the return keyword.

You can also return data in pointers:

```
void foo(int* c) {
    *c = 3;
}

int main(int argc, char**argv) {
   int h;
   foo(&h);
   printf("Foo returned %d\n", h);
   return 0;
 }
```

This is helpful if you have multiple values to return.

Answer (score 0):

Oh boy !

First what You are doing right or at least it seems so. You are drawing attention and get points for upvotes, despite the fact, that the code looks like typed in directly to the editor box on the Stackoverflow and never checked with any compiler. Good job :)

Now what's wrong. The list is long but some tips

```
void main()
{
    PERSON person[100];
    int *total;
    funcB(people, &total);
}

void funcB(PEOPLE people[], int *total);
```

It would be nice if You showed us the definitions of (probably) structs PEOPLE and PERSON.
In the code we can see, there is no definition of people - the variable you pass to funcB.
You define a pointer to int - total and don't initialize it. Then You pass an address of that pointer to funcB which takes int* not int** as a second argument. Those types are not compatible.

```
void funcB(PEOPLE people[], int *total)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", people[i].name);
    }
    funcA(people, &total);
}

void funcA(PEOPLE people[], int *total)
```

You use a pointer in the loop condition instead of the value pointed too. There is no value, because You didn't initialize the pointer in main, but here You have incompatible types in the condition. You pass an address of the pointer to funcA instead of the pointer, like in main.

```
void funcA(PEOPLE people[], int *total)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char line[100];
    fp = fopen("example.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        exit(1);
    }

    else {
        fgets(line, 100, fp);   //get a number from the txt
        total = atoi(linha);    //convert to int
    }
}
```

You use an undefined symbol 'linha' - I guess it's a misspelling of 'line'. Then You assign an int to a pointer instead of an int pointed to by that pointer.

Comment: Pointer should point to something. It's an int pointer so it should point to some int variable. Define an int variable and set the pointer to point to it. 

int myintvar;
int * mypointer = &myintvar;

Comment: and how about call the function?

Answer (score 0):

Check these:

1. `exit()` function exited from your program, not only from function. You can use `return;` to return from the function.
2. `total` is not initialized when you use that. Use `funcA(people, &total);` line before the for loop in your function `funcB`.